# How to Retrieve sql record which only have both ids

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT psam.ProductId, psam.SpecificationAttributeOptionId
                FROM Product_SpecificationAttribute_Mapping psam 
                WHERE psam.AllowFiltering = 1 
                and psam.SpecificationAttributeOptionId in (5,7)
```

Out Is:

```
ProductId  SpecificationAttributeOptionId
  11           5
  12           5
  11           7
  12           7
  44           7
```

i want records which have SpecificationAttributeOptionId 5 and 7 bith here in ProductId=44 doesn't have SpecificationAttributeOptionId=5 then olso its showing in record

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  psam.ProductId
FROM    Product_SpecificationAttribute_Mapping psam 
WHERE   psam.AllowFiltering = 1 AND 
        psam.SpecificationAttributeOptionId in (5,7)
GROUP   BY psam.ProductId
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2
```

The query above will output only two records: `11, 12`. If unique constraint was not enforce on `SpecificationAttributeOptionId` for every `ProductId` then a `DISTINCT` keyword is required,

```
SELECT  psam.ProductId
FROM    Product_SpecificationAttribute_Mapping psam 
WHERE   psam.AllowFiltering = 1 AND 
        psam.SpecificationAttributeOptionId in (5,7)
GROUP   BY psam.ProductId
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT psam.SpecificationAttributeOptionId) = 2
```

---

Lastly, if you want to get all records, you can wrap this query in a subquery and joined it on table `Product` so you can get all details,

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    Product_SpecificationAttribute_Mapping a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  psam.ProductId
            FROM    Product_SpecificationAttribute_Mapping psam 
            WHERE   psam.AllowFiltering = 1 AND 
                    psam.SpecificationAttributeOptionId in (5,7)
            GROUP   BY psam.ProductId
            HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2
        ) b ON a.ProductId = b.ProductId
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (**credits to hims056**)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4f6da/4)